# Alias in Python

Tags: python, syntax

Is there any way I can run a Python function by just typing a single word without parentheses? I notice that you can't just assign it like `x = function()` to a function, since that would be the value of the function at the moment.

Can't you assign the running of a function proper to a variable?

Comment: What about trying first?

Comment: You are asking two different questions...one about running (aka *calling*) a function, and one about assigning a function to a variable. You can *assign* by just doing `x = function` then you can *call* it with either `x()` or `function()`.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - how would you try when you don't know what to try?

Comment: You can do it with a setter in a class instance. Suppose you had class `Foo` with setter `bar` which is a method called on assignment. Then you could do `f = Foo()` and `f.bar = 999` and the _method_ is called.

Comment: By searching first? It's not 1980 any more - OP got all the keywords needed.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that's pretty unfair considering how unlikely it is that you even know what the OP is asking. I don't. It seems they are asking to "run Python function by just typing a single word without parentheses". I don't think that can be done, but searching for the negative is actually not that easy.

Comment: Well, what about "python function to variable" as a good start?

Comment: …which will bring you lots of examples of assigning a function to a variable and tell you nothing about how to "*run* Python function by just typing a single word without parentheses"

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can imagine any sane usecase for it, but you could subclass string and override the representation method to perform some side effect..

```py
In [15]: class StringWithSideEffect(str):
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         print("foo")
    ...:         return super().__repr__()
    ...:

In [16]: x = StringWithSideEffect("bar")

In [17]: x
Out[17]: foo
'bar'
```

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there is no such thing as assigning a function call to a variable.

however with the python built-in `property` class you can assign the call of a function to a class attribute:

```
class FunctionHook:
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        # args and kwargs are the arguments passed into the function
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    @property
    def get(self):  # or however you want to name the relevant attribute
        return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

# testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    a = FunctionHook(random.random)
    for _ in range(5):
        print(a.get)
    b = FunctionHook(random.randint, 13, 31)
    for _ in range(5):
        print(b.get)
```

output:

```
0.8434998046303654
0.2421758878321828
0.10999563726010275
0.3725559440217763
0.1906822598056529
29
28
27
31
13
```